# How to invoke a RESTful API and proccess response with Spring Integration WS

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-integration

Suppose I have another Spring Boot project with a controller like this:

```java
@RestController
public class TestController {

    @GetMapping("/test")
    public String test(@RequestBody String body) {
        log.info("/test: {}", body);
        return "[CHANGED] " + body;
    }
}
```

My goal is to redirect messages from a channel to the endpoint above. How do I do this properly?
I figured out SI has **Spring Integration Web Services** module for things like this, but I'm unable to make a working example. Here's my **IntegrationFlow**:

```java
public IntegrationFlow flow() {
    return IntegrationFlows.from(/* irrelevant */)
            .log(Object::toString)
            .handle(Ws.simpleOutboundGateway()
                    .uri("http://localhost:8080/test")
                    .requestCallback(message -> {
                        log.info("[REQUEST-CALLBACK] - Got response: {}", message);
                    })
            )
            .get();
}
```

The application fails to start with `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/soap/MessageFactory` error, so maybe I didn't provide enough parameters to the WS outbound gateway.

I googled the error and found out that adding this dependency should fix everything:

`compile group: 'javax.xml.soap', name: 'javax.xml.soap-api', version: '1.4.0'`

But it didn't. I keep getting errors about missing classes, just different ones.

My *dependecies* section looks like this:

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-json:2.4.0'
    implementation 'org.springframework.integration:spring-integration-core:5.4.1'
    implementation 'org.springframework.integration:spring-integration-ws:5.4.1'
    implementation 'com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat:jackson-dataformat-yaml:2.11.3'
    implementation 'com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat:jackson-dataformat-xml:2.11.3'

    compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    testImplementation('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test') {
        exclude group: 'org.junit.vintage', module: 'junit-vintage-engine'
    }
}
```

P.S. Sorry if the answer is somewhere on the surface (internet). Still learning, cannot fix this by myself.

**UPD: Java 11**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably didn’t read the docs correctly: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/ws.html#ws. The WS module of Spring Integration is fully based on the Spring WS project which goal is exactly about SOAP, not REST. Please, read respective specifications to see a difference.

To call a REST service you need Spring Integration HTTP module: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/http.html#http